# TypeORM: Access property with select:false inside class method of entity

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js, typeorm

I am building an application in Typescript using TypeORM, Express and Passport for authentication.

I have defined a user model in TypeORM within the file entities/User.ts.

The password field is protected using the column option `select: false` so that the password cannot be returned when fetching users (passwords are hashed and salted before insertion in the DB but I still dont want to ever return the hashed password over the API).

I have defined a validPassword method on the User which I use to check the password the user has entered matches the hashed password (using `bcrypt.compareSync`). The issue is that I cannot access this.password from within the validPassword method when `select: false` is set on the password field.

I know that it is possible to access the password from outside the class by using `addSelect` explicitly in the query builder, but I cannot get this to work from inside the validPassword method.

See below for the code of my User.ts file. The `validPassword` method works fine when I have `select: true` on `password`.

Any help appreciated.

```
// entities/User.ts
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, BeforeInsert } from "typeorm"

import bcrypt from "bcrypt-nodejs";
import IUser from "../auth/user.model";
import Logger from "../logging/logger";

@Entity()
export default class User implements IUser {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  userId: string

  @Column()
  username: string

  @Column( {select: false })
  password: string

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  email: string

  validPassword(password: string) {
    try {
      Logger.debug("Comparing PW");
      if(this.password && this.password != null) {
        const pwValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        return pwValid;
      } else {
        Logger.info("No PW")
        return false;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      Logger.error(`Error while comparing PW`, err.message);
    }
  }

  @BeforeInsert()
  hashPassword() {
    Logger.info("Hashing PW before save.")
    this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));
  }
}
```